# Angular 2 getting json data with ngfor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-http

I got a JSON array in URL and I am trying to get information from it so I could use it in `ngFor`. What am I doing wrong if I want to get link or name and use it in `ngFor`? Because I get it in `console.log(this.straip)`, but cannot use it in `ngFor`.

**Component.ts**

```
export interface straipsnelis {
  name: string;
  link: string;
}

straip = {} as straipsnelis;
ngOnInit() {
  this.http.get('this.url').subscribe((data:any) => {
    this.straip.link = data.map((a:any)=>a.guid);
    this.straip.name = data.map((a:any)=>a.slug);
    console.log(this.straip);
  })
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let s of straip" class="cardukas">
  <div class="left-photo">{{s.link}}</div>
  <div class="right-info"></div>
</div>
```

**Console error:**

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: plz provide console result

Comment: `straip` is not an object array.

Comment: How to convert it to object array ?

Comment: {link: Array(2), name: Array(2)}
link
:
Array(2)
0
:
{rendered: "http://life.optomeda.lt/?p=168"}
1
:
{rendered: "http://life.optomeda.lt/?p=1"}
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)
name
:
Array(2)
0
:
"h1-post-name-lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur-adipiscing-elit"
1
:
"pirmasis-tinklarascio-irasas"
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: add `this.straip = [this.straip]`

Comment: Angular **can't** loop an Object, ngFor supports iterables only, you need to provide an array.

Comment: But As I sent now, you can see from console it's two arrays. Name and link are arrays.

Comment: `straip = {} as straipsnelis` this should be `straip:straipsnelis[];`

Comment: I can't be , debug failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ngFor does not iterate on objects , it iterates on array only.

TS:

```
export interface straipsnelis {
  name: string;
  link: string;
}

straip = {} as straipsnelis;

straipArray : Array<any> = []; 

ngOnInit() {
  this.http.get('this.url').subscribe((data:any) => {
    this.straip.link = data.map((a:any)=>a.guid);
    this.straip.name = data.map((a:any)=>a.slug);
    this.straipArray.push(this.straip)

    console.log(this.straip);
  })
}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let s of straipArray" class="cardukas">
  <div class="left-photo">{{s.link}}</div>
  <div class="right-info"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get [object object] in html. No console error now.